# How do I position an iframe over the area map on mouseenter?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, area

Need a bit of help with this problem. I'm currently working on a project that requires me to create a web page that will use a 3D render of a server room as a background. Each server location is mapped to a rectangle area, on mouse enter I want to display a hidden iframe around that position.

I'm new to HTML, CSS and JS, I've got about 2 weeks experience and I can't seem to find the answers that will solve my problem.

[Current mouseenter popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSz6W.png)

As you can see from the image my mouseenter displays off the image and nowhere near the area rectangle.

I'll drop my code below, any tips/pointers will be appreciated.

```js
function popupshow(frameID) {
    let element = document.getElementById(frameID);
    let hidden = element.getAttribute("hidden");
    element.removeAttribute("hidden");
}
function popuphide(frameID) {
    let element = document.getElementById(frameID);
    let hidden = element.getAttribute("hidden");
    element.setAttribute("hidden", "hidden");
}
```

```css
#parent {
                position: relative;
                z-index: 15;
}
.popup {
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                z-index: 10
}
.graphPopupBelow {                                                                      /* Used to position the graph */
                display: none;
                position: absolute;
                border: 0px;
                width: 450px;
                height: 200px;
                top: 15px;
                left: 50px;
                z-index: 11
}
```

```html
<div>
<iframe class="graphPopupBelow" id="AHU1" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="AHU2" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="AHU3" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="Rack1" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="Rack4" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="Rack6" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="Rack12" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="Rack14" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>
<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="Rack16" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<div>
<iframe class="popup" id="J9" src="link url" hidden></iframe>
</div>

<img src="D6RenderFront.png" usemap="#image-map"><map name="image-map">
    <div id="map Rack1" class="parent"><area target="" alt="Rack 1" title="Rack 1" href="" coords="902,697,991,756" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('Rack1')" onmouseleave="popuphide('Rack1')"></div>

    <div id="map Rack4" class="parent"><area target="" alt="Rack 4" title="Rack 4" href="" coords="776,554,861,614" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('Rack4')" onmouseleave="popuphide('Rack4')"></div>

    <div id="map Rack6" class="parent"><area target="" alt="Rack 6" title="Rack 6" href="" coords="735,449,793,497" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('Rack6')" onmouseleave="popuphide('Rack6')"></div>

    <div id="map AHU3" class="parent"><area target="" alt="AHU 3" title="AHU 3" href="" coords="657,392,598,344" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('AHU3')" onmouseleave="popuphide('AHU3')"></div>

    <div id="map AHU2" class="parent"><area target="" alt="AHU 2" title="AHU 2" href="" coords="864,300,805,268" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('AHU2')" onmouseleave="popuphide('AHU2')"></div>

    <div id="map AHU1" class="parent"><area target="" alt="AHU 1" title="AHU 1" href="" coords="1030,173,1086,210" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('AHU1')" onmouseleave="popuphide('AHU1')"></div>

    <div id="map J9" class="parent"><area target="" alt="J9" title="J9" href="" coords="1076,526,1141,573" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('J9')" onmouseleave="popuphide('J9')"></div>

    <div id="map Rack12" class="parent"><area target="" alt="Rack 12" title="Rack 12" href="" coords="976,354,1034,380" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('Rack12')" onmouseleave="popuphide('Rack12')"></div>

    <div id="map Rack14" class="parent"><area target="" alt="Rack 14" title="Rack 14" href="" coords="1015,420,1074,454" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('Rack14')" onmouseleave="popuphide('Rack14')"></div>

    <div id="map Rack16" class="parent"><area target="" alt="Rack 16" title="Rack 16" href="" coords="1205,315,1156,285" shape="rect" onmouseenter="popupshow('Rack16')" onmouseleave="popuphide('Rack16')"></div>

</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors here :

- in your CSS you refer `#parent` with means a element where the id is parent
- the attributes that you put on your iframe should be on the parent div instead

Try to create a div that wraps all of your code and has the id parent instead.

Comment: Thanks for that input, I noticed the #parent error right after posting (silly me). I will give that a try, so far I've got the iframe to popup on mouseenter albeit in the top left corner of the image and not in the respective areas.

Comment: I was wondering if you know how I can get my iframe to pop up next to each area map co-ordinate, as each one is in a different area of the image I don't want to create a style for each iframe?